# How can I use Auth0 with .net core API and Angular?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, auth0

### My problematic

I'm trying to make a basic login page with Angular and asp.net core using Auth0 and I have no idea of how all this is working... I try to test my API before connecting it to Angular with Postman and every time I get a **Bearer error="invalid_token"** on postman even if I use the good token.

### Also

The documentation example only returns a message "Hello world" with the **Controller (Api endpoint)** and I don't even know what I am supposed to put thereafter to connect my controller and Angular service together, I'm sooo lost in all that codes...

Here is the documentation I'm looking for [.net core](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-core-webapi), [Angular](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login), and then to test the API with [Postman](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-core-webapi/02-using).

Please help me, thanks for the future answers!

### My appsettings.json

```
  "Auth0": {
    "Domain": "dev-icv0769a.us.auth0.com",
    "ApiIdentifier": "https://localhost:44398/api/Login/private"
  }
```

### My Startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });

            services.AddDbContext<CLDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            string domain = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/";
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = domain;
                options.Audience = Configuration["Auth0:ApiIdentifier"];
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier
                };
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("read:messages", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new HasScopeRequirement("read:messages", domain)));
            });

            // register the scope authorization handler
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, HasScopeHandler>();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

### My LoginController.cs

```
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("private")]
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Private()
        {
            return Ok(new
            {
                Message = "Hello from a private endpoint! You need to be authenticated to see this."
            });
        }

        [HttpGet("public")]
        public IActionResult Public()
        {
            return Ok(new
            {
                Message = "Hello from a public endpoint! You don't need to be authenticated to see this."
            });
        }

    }
```

**NOTE:** I also have **HasScopeHandler** and **HasScoreRequirement.cs** in my solution.

[**Postman response with the error message**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bYxe.png)

If you need something else to help me, just ask, thanks again!

Comment: Check your ASP.NET Core server logs for details on the authentication failure.

Comment: Where can I find thoses logs ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide an Authorization header in each request in order to access the `Private()` method:

```
Authorization: token_type + " " + access_token;
```

Comment: I did, but it wasn't working so I took an other approach with JWT and it's finally working !! But I appreciate the help, thanks you

Comment: Judging by your screenshot it looks like the Authorization header is missing in Postman, anyway, happy coding